# Laravel 5 Eloquent get only necessary result

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Heres is my code:

```
$data = Model::where('condition', $value)->get();
print_r($data);
```

How to get results only in eloquent? Its getting unnecessary keys.

```
$data['connection']
$data['guarded']
$data['etc.. etc etc...]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this to get all columns from Eloquent without any additional data:

```
$data = Model::where('condition', $value)->get()->toArray();
```

Or, if you need only some of the keys:

```
$data = Model::where('condition', $value)->get('valueIneed1', 'valueIneed2', 'valueIneed3')->toArray();
```

The thing is when you're using `get()`, you're getting an [`eloquent collection`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-collections) which contents a lot of additional data.